# connecting device without null modem cable

Tags: connection, cable, serial-port, null-modem

I have a data collector device which has a RS-232 male port, and the PC which sends data to that device has also a COM (RS-232) male port.

For wiring I have a RS-232 cable (male to female) and a [gender changer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_changer).

```
PC---gender changer------RS-232 cable---------data collector device
```

But it seems not work; the device is not receiving data.
I assume that I may need a null modem cable. How can I solve this problem even without having a null modem cable? is there a software can change the wiring/pin assignment from PC side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get null modem adapters/cables for cheap these days, it's your best bet.

RS-232 ports are very much hardware-centric. You'd have better luck rewiring the pins on the motherboard than trying to find a motherboard that allows BIOS-level pin reassignment, let alone software-level.

You could possibly hack and rewire your serial cable into a null modem cable.  Pin-out information is available [here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232_null_modem.html) (amongst many other places).  I wouldn't trust doing this, due to signal interference.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You will need a null modem cable.  This cannot be done with software.

Answer (score 0):

Hit your local electronic parts house and get a null-modem adapter.  Replace the gender bender with the adapter and you should be set.

If you have a Radio Shack nearby, they carry them for about $13.00.